safe w/ 4337 module & entrypoint 0.7
We need to setup a safe account with the 4337 module. Using pimlico bundler (w/ and w/o paymaster) with entrypoint 0.7. Seems to deploy ok and can send transactions w/ and w/o paymaster via the pimlico bundler. So far so good.
But trying to import the api created safe account to the safe wallet, complains that this is a safe from an incompatible Base contract. Is this just a frontend thing that will get updated in due course?
I can see that only a safe deployed to sepolia works with the frontend while safes on every other network we tried (42161, 421614, 10, 11155420) seems to have the issue.

Unfortunately safes deployed from another safe proxy factory than the "official" one deployed for that network (list available here) won't be natively supported on the UI. We are currently looking into ways to still make that compatibility possible (it's harder than it looks), but in the meantime, we recommend using the CLI to interact with that safe.
Can you confirm these safes were not deployed using the factories listed in the supported networks documentation?
Thank you in advance  Louis

I'm using the official 1.4.1 contracts from that repository but guess the page mentions 1.4.1 isn't fully supported. More discussions with your team started here on github and they are acknowledging the issue and awaiting response from the safe core team!? https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/issues/3647#issuecomment-2137387648

I got confirmation from the Core team that we were still working on supporting the 4337 implementation in the UI until just now. Can please you confirm it is now working?

arbitrum works now. Optimism is still showing the warning. I added the chain request here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/issues/1009

Perfect, thank you! Feel free to mark the question as solved then

Arbitrum is now fixed for sure but optimism continues to show the warning. While I added the contract details to the safe-eth-py repo as referenced earlier and the PR seems to have been accepted and merged, I still see the warning.
So I am not sure I really understand the process. Is the same safe-wallet-web somehow reading the allowlisted contracts in safe-eth-py? Because in gnosis/safe/addresses.py there, 1.4.1+L2 is defined for optimism but not arbitrum while my warning issue is the other way around.

After the PR has been merged in safe-eth-py it will also have to be added to the wallet UI, which can take a bit more time. Please hang tight as we're working on solving the issue
